# Tornado substituting custom logger on server (not on local computer)

Tags: python, logging, server, tornado, python-logging

I have a tornado application and a custom logger method. My code to build and use the custom logger is the following:

```
def create_logger():
    """
    This function creates the logger functionality to be used throughout the Python application
    :return: bool - true if successful
    """
    # Configuring the logger
    filename = "PythonLogger.log"

    # Change the current working directory to the logs folder, so that the logs files is written in it.
    os.chdir(os.path.normpath(os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + os.sep + os.pardir + os.sep + os.pardir + os.sep + 'logs')))

    # Create the logs file
    logging.basicConfig(filename=filename,  format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filemode='w')

    # Creating the logger
    logger = logging.getLogger()

    # Setting the threshold of logger to DEBUG
    logger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)

    logger.log(0, 'El logger está inicializado')

    return True

def log_info_message(msg):
    """
    Utility for message logging with code 20
    :param msg:
    :return:
    """
    return logging.getLogger().log(20, msg)
```

In the code, I initialize the logger and already write a message to it before the Tornado application initialization:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':


    # Logger initialization
    create_logger()

    # First log message
    log_info_message('Initiating Python application')

    # Starting Tornado
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()

    # Specifying what app exactly is being started
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(test.app)
    server.listen(options.port)

    try:
        if 'Windows_NT' not in os.environ.values():
            server.start(0)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
```

Then let's say my method get of HTTP request is as follows (only interesting lines):

```
class API(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

        def get(self):
            self.write('Get request    ')
            logging.getLogger("tornado.access").log(20, 'Hola') 
            logging.getLogger("tornado.application").log(20, '1')
            logging.getLogger("tornado.general").log(20, '2')
            log_info_message('Received a GET request at: ' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f)"))
```

What I see is a difference between local testing and testing on server.

A) On local, I can see log message at first script running, and log messages of requests (after initializing Tornado app) in my log file and the Tornado logs.

B) On server, I only see the first message, not my log messages when Get requests are accepted and also see Tornado's loggers when there's an error, but even don't see the messages produced by Tornado's loggers. I guess that means that somehow Tornado is re-initializing the logger and making mine and his 3 ones write in some other file (somehow that does not affect when errors happens??).

I am aware that Tornado uses its own 3 logging functions, but somehow I would like to use mine as well, at the same time as keeping the Tornado's ones and writing them all into the same file. Basically reproduce that local behaviour on server but also keeping it when some error happens, of course.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: if I add a name to the logger, let's say `logging.getLogger('Example')` and changed log_info_message function to `return logging.getLogger('Example').log(20, msg)`, Tornado's logger would fail and raise error. So that option destroys its own loggers...

Comment: Your code has `import tornado` at the top, right? The first module that initializes logging gets to call the shots. If you want control,  create your logger before doing that import.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only made the code to fail on server, though it's working fine on local machine

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only problem was that, on the server side, tornado was setting the the mininum level for a log message to be written on log file higher (minimum of 40 was required). So that `logging.getLogger().log(20, msg)` would not write on the logging file but `logging.getLogger().log(40, msg)` would.

I would like to understand why, so if anybody knows, your knowledge would be more than welcome. For the time being that solution is working though.

Answer (score 0):

`tornado.log` defines [options](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/log.html#define_logging_options) that can be used to customise logging via command line (check [tornado.options](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/options.html)) - one of them is `logging` that defines the log level used. You are likely using this on the server and setting it to `error`.

When debugging logging I suggest you create a `RequestHandler` that will log or return the structure of the existing loggers by inspecting the root logger. When you see the structure it is much easier to understand why it works the way it works.